# Why ajax calls trigger the evaluation of any <ui:repeat>, even residing outside the render area?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

Frankly, I do not understand why JSF would need to evaluate the `<ui:repeat>`'s `value` attribute in the example below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
  <h:head/>
  <h:body>
    <h:form>
      <h:panelGroup id="date" layout="block">
        <h:outputText value="#{testBean.currentDate}"/>
      </h:panelGroup>

      <h:commandButton value="Ajax!">
        <f:ajax execute="@this" render="date"/>
      </h:commandButton>

      <!-- "value" attr gets evaluated per each ajax call -->
      <ui:repeat value="#{testBean.list1}" var="obj" >
        <h:outputText value="#{obj}"/>
      </ui:repeat>

      <!-- no evaluation happens here -->
      <h:dataTable value="#{testBean.list2}" var="obj">
        <h:column>
          <h:outputText value="#{obj}"/>
        </h:column>
      </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

And why this is not the case with `h:dataTable`? Any ideas?

In case it matters, here is the bean class I used:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

  private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TestBean.class.getName());
  private static final List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");

  public List<String> getList1() {
    LOG.info("Evaluated 1");
    return list;
  }

  public List<String> getList2() {
    LOG.info("Evaluated 2");
    return list;
  }

  public String getCurrentDate() {
    return (new Date()).toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Most likely a bug/oversight in Mojarra. I'm contacting one of the devs, stay tuned ...

Comment: @BalusC, thanks. Here is the Mojarra version: Mojarra 2.2.0 (20130502-2118 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.0@11930), server - GF4